# Как влияет символ "Z" в конце даты на JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть проблема с разницей во времени при `.getHours()`. Пусть есть дата `2019-09-20T15:20:23Z`. При получении от этой даты `.getHours()` я получаю значение 18. При получении часов от `2019-09-20T15:20:23.000` я получаю значение 15. Как влияет "Z", как это исправить средствами самого JS (никаких сторонних библиотек) и как получать верное значение часов. Мне нужно получать конкретно то значение, которое указано в дате, без этой разницы в 3 часа.

Comment: Z - это [timezone](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Z - указывает, что время в UTC. Если Z отсутствует, то считается, что время местное. 
Поэтому при наличии Z у Вас добавляется разница между UTC и Вашим часовым поясом.

Чтобы избежать путаницы, Вы можете все значения даты и времени:

- хранить в UTC (рекомендуется).
- хранить в местном времени (не рекомендуется (из-за разницы часовых поясов например время 12:00 зафиксированное в Москве будет соответствовать 21:00 на Чукотке, а пользователь на Чукотке увидит 12:00))

Подробнее [тут](https://msiter.ru/tutorials/javascript/js_date_formats).

Для более удобной работы с датой и временем (особенно с учётом часовых поясов) лучше использовать [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), а не работать с ними напрямую.

Comment: да, moment - это тема, + он еще юзается во многих датапикерах и у него есть поддержка локалей

Answer (score 2):

Часть `Z` обозначает временную зону – в формате `+-hh:mm`, либо символ Z, обозначающий UTC. По стандарту её можно не указывать, тогда UTC, но в Safari с этим ошибка, так что лучше указывать всегда.

Например:

`var msUTC = Date.parse('2012-01-26T13:51:50.417Z');`

`var ms = Date.parse('2012-01-26T13:51:50.417-07:00');`

Взято с [отсюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime)